# Issue while updating copy activity in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to update a source excel column with a particular string.
My source contains n columns. I need to check where the string apple exists in any one of the columns. If the value exist in any column I  need to replace the apple with orange string. And output the excel. How can I do this in ADF?

Note:I cannot use dataflows since we were using a self hosted vm

Comment: The `azure-data-explorer` tag does not seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files has lot of **limitations** in ADF like **it is not supported in the copy activity sink** and in **Data flow sink** as well.
You can raise the feature request for that in ADF.

So, try the above operation with a csv and copy the result to a csv in blob which later you can change it to Excel in your local machine.

To do the operations like above, Data flow can be a better option than doing it with normal activities as Dataflow deals with the transformations.
But Data flow won't support Self hosted linked service.

So, as a workaround first copy the **Excel file as csv to Blob storage using copy activity**. Create a Blob linked service for that to use in dataflow.

Now follow the below process in Data flow.

**Source CSV from Blob:**

[image]

**Derived column transformation:**

give the condition for each column `case(col1=="apple", "orange", col1)`

[image]

**Sink :**

In Sink settings specify as Output to single file.

[image]

After Pipeline execution a csv will be generated in the blob. You can convert it to Excel in your local machine.

Comment: Hi RakeshGovindula, Note:I cannot use dataflows since we were using a self hosted vm So how can i use dataflows

Comment: HI @BeingReal, that means you are accessing data from self hosted VM using copy activity with the help self hosted Integration runtime right. So My suggestion is first copy excel file from your self hosted VM to Azure Blob storage as csv file using copy activity. Then create a Blob linked service for that csv file with Azure Integration runtime as Dataflows supports only Azure IR. Then you can follow the procedure I have provided above.

Comment: HI  
@RakeshGovindula ,then create a Blob linked service for that csv file with Azure Integration runtime as Dataflows supports only Azure IR               I already commeneted that i cannot use Azure Integration runtime due to business prohibitions.

Comment: Okay, I am also working on this without Dataflows. when I got it, I'll update here.

Comment: @ RakeshGovindula Sure Please update here once yu find a soln Thanks btw